# Implicit within pattern match

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, pattern-matching, implicit

I have a method, with have a lot of implicit parameters:

```
def hello(message:String)(implicit a:A,b:B,c:C, ..., user: User) = {...}
```

Now consider such a class:

```
object Users extends Controller {
  implicit a: A = ...
  implicit b: B = ...
  ...

  def index(id:String) = Action {
     User.findById(id) match {
       case Some(user) => {
          implicit val _user = user
          hello("implicit")
       }
       case _ => BadRequest
     }
  }
}
```

You can see this line in the above sample:

```
implicit val _user = user
```

It exists just to make the object `user` as an implicit object. Otherwise, I have to call `hello` as:

```
hello("implicit")(a,b,c,... user)
```

I'm thinking if there is any way to improve the code, e.g. we don't need to define that `_user` variable but make the `user` is implicit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to eliminate `_user` variable while making `user` implicit:

```
def index(id:String) = Action {
  User.findById(id) map (implicit user => hello("implicit")) getOrElse BadRequest
}
```

**UPDATE:** Addressing your question about many cases in the comments below.

It all depends what value type is returned by `User.findById`. If it's `Option[User]` but you want to match on specific users (assuming `User` is a case class), then the original solution still applies:

```
def index(id:String) = Action {
  User.findById(id) map { implicit user =>
    user match {
      case User("bob") => hello("Bob")
      case User("alice") => hello("Alice")
      case User("john") => hello("John")
      case _ => hello("Other user")
    }
  } getOrElse BadRequest
```

Or you can match on anything else if you want, as long as `User.findById` is `String => Option[User]`

If, on the other hand, `User.findById` is `String => User` then you can simply define a helper object like:

```
object withUser {
  def apply[A](user: User)(block: User => A) = block(user)
}
```

And use it as follows (again assuming `User` is a case class):

```
def index(id: String) = Action {
  withUser(User findById id) { implicit user =>
    user match {
      case User("bob") => hello("Bob")
      case User("alice") => hello("Alice")
      case User("john") => hello("John")
      case _ => BadRequest
    }
  }
}
```

or matching on some other value, say an `Int`:

```
def index(id: String, level: Int) = Action {
  withUser(User findById id) { implicit user =>
    level match {
      case 1 => hello("Number One")
      case 2 => hello("Number Two")
      case 3 => hello("Number Three")
      case _ => BadRequest
    }
  }
}
```

I hope this covers all the scenarios you may have.

Comment: +1, it's a good solution if pattern match an `Option`. But what if there are many `case`s?

Answer (score 2):

I know of no trick such as case `Some(implicit user)` but what about

```
def hello(message: String, user: User)(implicit a: A, ... z: Z) = ...
def hello(message: String)(implicit a: A, ... z: Z, user: User) = hello(message, user)

case Some(user) => hello("implicit", user)
```

Comment: Thank you. I think `hello(message)(implicit ...)` should be the existing one and can't be changed, otherwise we don't need to define it, just define a `hello(message,user)(implicit ...)` on is enough.